# ng-include on SVG's but including dimensions

Tags: angularjs, svg

I like this technique, but as you all know, one of the great things about svg graphics is that you can re-size and re-use the same file. Is it possible to add a size variable to ng-include?

eg:

```
<div ng-include="'img/logo-rev.svg'" class="ng-scope" width="50">
```

Comment: I think you should use height and width in the logo-rev.svg file in the <svg> tag.

Comment: Hey! Yeah got that, but what about if you want the logo.svg in the login page as 200px and the header as 70px. If you have the width in svg you can't resize using ng-include.

Comment: maybe if you set the width or height using percentages instead fixed values, this way the logo shall take the size of the container element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to not specify a `width` or `height` in your SVG. Or if you do, make sure they are both set to `"100%"`.  Then as long as your SVG has a suitable `viewBox` attribute, it will scale to whatever size you make its parent.

```css
.small {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.large {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="small">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="green"/>
  </svg>
</div>


<div class="large">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="green"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Note that the two SVGs in the example above are identical.